# accessing an element of a django database object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am trying to access an element of a django database table object.
My under standing is the structure is as follows:

> Database table -> object -> elements.

I can access the Database object that i want by doing the following:

```
    wanted_object = WholeValues.objects.get(id=1)
```

how can I access the the elements of this database object.
I have tried `wanted_element = wanted_object.get(id=2)`
when I try to access the first element I get an error.
this error says `WholeValues' object has no attribute 'get'`

My model for the object is as follows:

```
class WholeValues(models.Model):
    a_count = models.FloatField()
    b_count = models.FloatField()
    c_count = models.FloatField()
```

in my specific case I want to access the b_count value.

Comment: `wanted_object.b_count`?

Comment: What do you consider an *"element"*? Another instance of your model or an attribute of the instance you have already retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wanted_object` is a `WholeValues` instance.
you can access to its fields or methods like any normal python object.

```
# Get object where `id = 1` from database
wanted_object = WholeValues.objects.get(id=1)

# object.<field_name> to access object fields
print(wanted_object.a_count)
```